# How to disable comment folding in ShellEd

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I installed [ShellEd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/shelled/), a shell script editor for Eclipse.

It folds multiline-comments by default, and I can't find an option to turn it off. Is there such an option, and if so, where?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click on the folding symbol in the editor, select Folding from the menu, then choose your preferred option.

Took me MONTHS to find out myself.

Comment: it just made me crazy when I opend a source file and showing me multi-line comments for have a second and then hiding/folder happend ....Rrrrr... BUT: I had to do the following to permanently disable that nonsense: Windows | Preferences "folding" > Uncheck "Enable folding when opening a new editor".

Answer (score 3):

This is just to expand on the correct answer already given by user3280555.

The keyboard short-cut to do this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad_divide</kbd>

If you want to do the same with your mouse:

This is what is meant by the "Folding symbol" on the editor:

[image]

Once you right click on it, simply uncheck: `Folding > Enable Folding`

Comment: Permanently disable "folding": Windows | Preferences "folding" > Uncheck "Enable folding when opening a new editor"